# How to alert the textbox in jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a text box in jquery

```
row.append($('<TD ><input type="text" value=' + item.Marks1 + ' size="10px" class="marks" id="txtmarks1" ></td>'));
```

Now i want to validate the text box (must not exceed more than 100)

Comment: if (row.val() > 100) //do error thing  ?  I don't understand your question..

Comment: question is not clear. what you want to do?

Comment: i want just validation for that text box

Answer (score 0):

```
row.append($('<TD ><input maxlength="100" type="text" value=' + item.Marks1 + ' size="10px" class="marks" id="txtmarks1" ></td>'));
```

adding this attribute: maxlength="100"

Answer (score 0):

If you wanna validate input string length:

```
if ($('#txtmarks1').val().length> 100){
        //error handler
    }
```

Comment: only THIS td or only tds with this class?

Comment: I edit answer, maybe this work?   $('#txtmarks1').val().length

Comment: Maybe you will create sample on jsfiddle (your html, css and js code)? Then we will can see and understand your problem and help you.